# Mule - Spring - Pass properties to Java Class

Tags: java, spring, properties, mule

This is my mule flow:

```
<spring:beans>

    <spring:bean id="component" name="component" lazy-init="false" class="java.delete.DeleteFiles">
        <spring:property name="messageJSON" value="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]"/>
    </spring:bean>
    
</spring:beans>

<flow name="javatestFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <set-payload value="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <set-property propertyName="message" value="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" doc:name="Property"/>
    <component doc:name="Java">
        <spring-object bean="component"/>
    </component>
</flow>
```

And in my Java class I implements the `Callable class` from Mule.

```
public class DeleteFiles implements Callable {

    public String messageJSON;
    
    public String getmessageJSON() {
        return messageJSON;
    }

    public void setmessageJSON(String messageJSON) {
        this.messageJSON = messageJSON;
    }

    @Override
    public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(messageJSON);
        
        String msj = eventContext.getSession().getProperty("messageJSON");
        System.out.println(msj);
        
        return null;
    }

}
```

The first SysOut returns me:

> ## [message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]

And the second:

> null

What should I do to get the value from a property in my mule flow with Spring and Java?

Comment: try to post all your class

Comment: @Abdelhak I've added all the Java class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was use an `OutboundProperty` in Java:

```
    @Override
    public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
        String propertyDir = eventContext.getMessage().getOutboundProperty("messageJSON");
        System.out.println(propertyDir);
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: You can also try this: eventContext.getMessage().getProperty("messageJSON", PropertyScope.OUTBOUND);